# extra links from foreach in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm on a mac using GNU Make to manage my dotfiles. There's a directory with my emacs config files and a corresponding target in the Makefile:

```
all: _emacs
.PHONY: all list $(MAKECMDGOALS)

....

EMACS_SOURCE_DIR   := $(abspath ./emacs)
EMACS_TARGET_DIR   := $(abspath $(HOME)/.emacs.d)
EMACS_CONFIG_FILES := $(wildcard $(EMACS_SOURCE_DIR)/*.el)

_emacs: | $(EMACS_TARGET_DIR)

    @echo $(call message,"Setting up config files for emacs")
    $(foreach file, \
     $(EMACS_CONFIG_FILES), \
     ln -sf $(file) $(addsuffix /, $(EMACS_TARGET_DIR)))

$(EMACS_TARGET_DIR):
    @echo "Creating directory $(EMACS_TARGET_DIR)"
    @mkdir -p $@
```

When I run `make _emacs` it creates some extra links:

```
     .emacs.d -> /Users/xxx/.emacs.d/
          -sf -> -sf
early-init.el -> /Users/xxx/Projects/bootstrap/emacs/early-init.el
  init-org.el -> /Users/xxx/Projects/bootstrap/emacs/init-org.el
 init-pkgs.el -> /Users/xxx/Projects/bootstrap/emacs/init-pkgs.el
      init.el -> /Users/xxx/Projects/bootstrap/emacs/init.el
           ln -> ln
```

I'm struggling to understand what exactly is happening and how to avoid having the first two and the last soft links created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's a bad idea to try to construct a complex shell command using make functions inside a recipe.  You should simply use shell constructs: for example use the shell `for` loop, not the make `foreach` loop.

Let's see what your recipe does:

```
_emacs: | $(EMACS_TARGET_DIR)
        $(foreach file, \
         $(EMACS_CONFIG_FILES), \
         ln -sf $(file) $(addsuffix /, $(EMACS_TARGET_DIR)))
```

Make functions manipulate *text*.  They don't know anything about commands, shell syntax, etc.  Before make invokes the shell it first expands the script.  What will this result in?  This:

```
ln -sf .../emacs/early-init.el /Users/xxx/.emacs.d/ ln -sf .../emacs/init-org.el /Users/xxx/.emacs.d/ ln -sf ...
```

Maybe now you can see the problem.

If you wanted to do this using make's `foreach` you have to add a shell delimiter so the shell knows where one command ends and the next begins; something like:

```
        $(foreach file, \
         $(EMACS_CONFIG_FILES), \
         ln -sf $(file) $(addsuffix /, $(EMACS_TARGET_DIR)) ; )
```

(note the `;` at the end).  Now when make expands it will look like this:

```
ln -sf .../emacs/early-init.el /Users/xxx/.emacs.d/ ; ln -sf .../emacs/init-org.el /Users/xxx/.emacs.d/ ; ln -sf ...
```

If I were you, I'd instead use a shell loop.  It's just much simpler to understand:

```
        for file in $(EMACS_CONFIG_FILES); do \
           ln -sf $$file $(addsuffix /, $(EMACS_TARGET_DIR)) ; \
        done
```

But, for what you want to do you don't need a loop at all; you can link multiple files into the same directory with one command:

```
        ln -sf $(EMACS_CONFIG_FILES) $(EMACS_TARGET_DIR)
```

(I'm not sure what the `addsuffix` was needed for, or why you couldn't just write it as `$(EMACS_TARGET_DIR)/` without the `addsuffix`)

Comment: I was using that `addsuffix` thingy to rename target links, e.g. `zshrc -> .zshrc`. You're right, it does nothing in this case. Thx for your help!